# how-to force internet traffic go via a proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, squid

Could you please advise me on the following:

*infra-server* has no internet connectivity. *proxy-server* has internet connectivity

When I do from the infra-server

```
infra-server#export http_proxy=http://proxy-server:8888
```

and then

```
infra-server# telnet google.com 80
Trying 172.217.22.110...
^C
```

What I get is (the request is NOT sent via the proxy)

```
15:52:34.932364 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 12417, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    x.x.x.x.53769 > 172.217.22.110.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xfd83 (incorrect -> 0xbe35), seq 1333303030, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3139741303 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:52:35.932672 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 12418, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
```

but using the port 80, instead of port 888

Could you please advise me what am doing wrong ?

Comment: don't you normally require some kind of login password? or .pac file? 
export http_proxy=http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@proxy-server.com:8888/              and keep in mind that things like yum or other applications might require you to put proxy configuration within conf files.

Comment: telnet doesn't use `http_proxy` environment. Only http clients use it.
To force telnet over http, then use `httptunnel`

Comment: Sorry, not `httptunnel`, `proxytunnel` what you want.